# how to have a base layout in mustache for spring-boot?

Tags: spring-boot, mustache

Hi is there a way I can have a base layout, like in express for node, [see here](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars) , when using mustache for spring boot? So that I could do:

base layout:

```
<html>
   <body>
   <p>Title</p>
   {{{body}}} // or similar, not sure about #
</html>
```

and then use the Controller's returned view name as content to render a view, so the outside is always the same?

Comment: The spring boot mustache starter pack uses a version of mustache for java that doesn't support inheritance. I switched to pebble for this exact reason; similar, clean syntax, and full inheritance support. Guide here: http://www.mitchellbosecke.com/pebble/documentation/guide/spring-integration

Answer (score 3):

You can do this via Mustache lambda functions. With this tutorial I was able to achieve what you need: https://spring.io/blog/2016/11/21/the-joy-of-mustache-server-side-templates-for-the-jvm#layout-abstractions-using-a-lambda

Create a controller advice like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
class LayoutAdvice {

  @ModelAttribute("layout")
  public Mustache.Lambda layout() {
    return new Layout();
  }
}

class Layout implements Mustache.Lambda {

  String body;

  @Override
  public void execute(Fragment frag, Writer out) throws IOException {
    body = frag.execute();
  }
}
```

This will make a lambda function named "layout" accessible for your Mustache templates. The lambda function itself receives the fragment (which will be inside the layout tags, see below) and store it in the layout object's `body` field. This will be accessible from the layout template:

```
<html>
<body>
    {{{layout.body}}}
</body>
</html>
```

The filename must be "layout.html" as we used `@ModelAttribute("layout")` above.

Then you can use your layout by calling the lambda function and passing a fragment which will be the body of your layout:

```
{{#layout}}
    <h1>Demo</h1>
    <div>Hello World</div>
{{/layout}}
{{>layout}}
```

It will produce the desired output:

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Demo</h1>
    <div>Hello World</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Usually you should not just post a link, but also quote the most relevant part and explain how it applies to the question asked: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Okay-okay, I am editing my answer and adding context right now, sorry! :)

Comment: Okay, I added quotes and explanation to my answer. Sorry.